How to put y-axis label on right side with plt.tick_params?
I see lots of examples putting y-axis label and ticks with
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

but I can't find any examples doing the same thing with plt.tick_params. I was able to put ticks and tick values on the right side by
plt.tick_params(axis='y', left=False, labelleft=False, right=True, labelright=True)

but I can't figure out a way to put plt.ylabel("y-axis") on the right side. How do I do this?

It's not clear what you want to achieve. At the end you say that you want the Y label on the right but at the begining you say that yaxis.set_label_position('right') put the Y label on the right ...

It does seem odd that there is a pyplot function for moving the ticks across but apparently no pyplot function for moving the y-label across.
